# Plotting different mixture model clusters in the same curve

Tags: r, gmm

I have two sets of data, one representing a healthy data set having 4 variables and 11,000 points and another representing a faulty set having 4 variables and 600 points. I have used R's package MClust to obtain GMM clustering for each data set separately. What I want to do is to obtain both clusters in the same frame so as to study them at the same time. How can that be done?

I have tried joining both the datasets but the result I am obtaining is not what I want.

The code in use is:

```
    Dat4M <- Mclust(Dat3, G = 3)
```

Dat3 is where I am storing my dataset, Dat4M is where I store the result of Mclust. G = 3 is the number of Gaussian mixtures I want, which in this case is three. To plot the result, the following code is used:

```
    plot(Dat4M)
```

The following is obtained when I apply the above code in my Healthy dataset:

[image: Density curve for Healthy data G = 3]

The following is obtained when the above code is used on Faulty dataset:

[image: Density curve for Faulty data G = 3]

Notice that in the faulty data density curve, consider the mixture of CCD and CCA, we see that there are two density points that have been obtained. Now, I want to place the same in the same block in the healthy data and study the differences.

Any help on how to do this will be appreciated.